# how do you turn off the word plane wireframe? industrial keymap

Tags: modeling

for the word plane I do mean the grid like section, subdivided by squares and by yx green and red axis

[image]

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify a little what you mean?

Comment: I think `rg4g44` maybe means the "world plane" wireframe--i.e., the gizmo grid showing even spacing in the background?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett edited

Comment: Just click those two little overlapping circles (one solid, one outline - currently highlighted blue) in the top right of the viewport (Show Overlays). You can access more related controls if you click the little down arrow right beside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top row of menus in the 3D Viewport is called the *header*.  On the right, although they may be too far right to see if you've shrunk the viewport, are a set of icons that look like:

[image: header icons in 3d viewport]

The 3rd Icon, the thing that looks like a solid filled circle and an outline circle, is the *Overlay* Menu.  If you click on the ↓ that looks like a lower case v, it will open to show:

[image: Overlay menu expanded]

The first row under *guides* contains entries for *floor* and X and Y *axis*.  Disabling *floor* will disable the grid but leave the axis visible.

[image: floor disabled]

You need to also disable X and Y axis if you want no visible floor at all.

Comment: Just to add to @Marty Fouts answer, if the icon **is** hidden because the viewport is too narrow, you can drag the entire header bar left and right by holding the middle mouse button down when the cursor is over the header.